# Ajax vs webservices

Tags: ajax, web-services

what is different between ajax and webservices. Anybody provide with some examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term "[Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)" is generally used :

- When the request is sent by a browser (client-side) to a server
- When the transfered data is XML or JSON or HTML.

The word "[webservice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webservice)" is generally used :

- When the request is sent by a server to another server, without a browser being involved
- When the transfered data is SOAP -- at least when it's a SOAP webservice ^^ *(Opposed to REST, for instance, which generally doesn't imply SOAP)*

But I'd say that Ajax is basically some specific kind of webservice.

Comment: "Ajax is a kind of webservice"? I really disagree with that; it makes no sense to me. Ajax is an *action*, Webservice is an API running on a server available for calling. You can't compare them.

Comment: Using an Ajax request to get some data, a request is sent, via the network, some action is done on the server, some data is returned and processed ; kinda fits in the "generalistic" webservice description, in my opinion

Comment: You're referring to the process of making a "webservice *call*". Obviously making a "webservice call" from a browser effectively means "Ajax". But a "webservice" does not relate to a "Ajax". What is "a Ajax"? It's nonsense.

Comment: I agree with Noon. Ajax is a pattern of web service interaction found in html pages.

Answer (score 7):

It's nonsensical to compare these things.

"Ajax" is a process that occurs in the browser. It is the act of calling some local server-side page, without refreshing the "main" viewing area, and then doing various things with that result (grabbing the data, making changes, changing the existing DOM (adding elements), whatever).

Webservices are a Serverside-thing that allows you to call methods, in your code, but have that call actually go to a remote machine. The call to the Webservice is generally also made server-side.

Answer (score -2):

i think ajax and web services are kind of similar, here is why i think so.
as i understood it, in your app sometimes you will have to implement an "API" which has several useful functions. and it is those functions which are called "web services". these 'functions' acts in response to the http requests and "does" something with the data provided.
in ajax siimilar kind of work happens as well,just through javascript thats it.
so, to sum it all up, an API has 'web services' within it, and ajax behaves like 'web services'. in this manner, yes i think it is correct to call ajax and web services similar.

Comment: Actually ajax and web services are two completely different things. Ajax is a pattern on web service interaction tied to html pages. Ajax uses web services, but itself is not one.

Comment: i didn't say they are the same thing, i said they are kind of similar!

Comment: That is, as if you would say, a fork and spaghetti are kind of similiar, because, they are both involved in eating.